# Will promise execute one by one if they are put in same file?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

Considering I have 1 function that return a promise in a file

```
public async a():Promise<string>{
  return 'hi'
}
```

And in another file I use this function like this way.

```
await service.a.then( hi =>console.log(hi)).catch(err=>{throw err});
await service.a.then( hi =>console.log(hi)).catch(err=>{throw err});
```

will they run one after another and have no intersaction problem?
thank you.

Comment: You're not actually returning a promise in `a()` since you're only returning the string 'hi'. But assuming you're actually returning a promise, yes, await will make sure that one promise is called before the other. In fact, await is just syntactic sugar for chaining promises with then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comment, I find out they do run one after another after some testing.
Thank you.